# How to Create a file download link in a page template

Tags: php, wordpress, download

I need to download a file on click of a link in word press. 
I have file url.
I know the download code in php and I added in functions.php.

```
function downloadFile($f){
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . urlencode($f));
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Type: application/download');
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($f));
    echo file_get_contents($f);
}
```

Now how to call this function on click of a link? What will be the "href" of the link

Answer (score 3):

On the page with the link:

```
<a href="download.php?f=foo">Download "Foo"</a>
```

On `download.php` (or whatever name you choose):

```
include "functions.php";
downloadFile($_GET["f"]);
exit;
```

---

**Edit** Or just create a `download.php` page:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["f"])){
        $f = $_GET["f"];
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.urlencode($f));
        header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Type: application/download');
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($f));
        echo file_get_contents($f);
    }
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: WordPress is not out of PHP.

Comment: I know how to do this in php. I need to know how to do this in wordpress. I know wordpress is not out of php. But I wanna know the framework way of doing this.

Comment: *There isn't one*. You have to make it yourself. Or just create a `download.php` page, ignore the `functions.php` page and just write the code to handle the downloads in one page.

Comment: Where should I create download.php? Right in the theme path? Will the url directly reference download.php?

Comment: I created download.php. But onclick of link it just says page not found

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a function, what you can do is to **create a new Page in the Wordpress backend** and put your php headers in a custom template for that page, like so (simple pdf download):

```
<?php
// Specify wordpress template name
/* Template Name: Download Page */

// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

// Set filename of download
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="FILENAME.pdf"');

// Path to the file (searching in wordpress template directory)
$url = get_template_directory_uri() . "/folder/ORIGINAL_FILE.pdf";

readfile($url);
?>
```

Then you can simply put the permalink to your new wordpress page as the href on the download link. Permalinks for wordpress pages can be edited at will at the wordpress backend, so you could make it something like:

www.example.com/downloadfile

I know it's old but I recently had this problem as well, hope it helps anyone who ended up here as well!