# WooCommerce download file from server to the client browser after order is completed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Currently I have the following code in the functions.php which executed twice, once when order in processing and again after it is completed.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'executeFile', 10, 3 );
function executeFile( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status ) {
    if ( $new_status == "processing" ) {

        file_put_contents(wp_upload_dir()['basedir'].'/filetodownload.txt', 'some text');

        $order->update_status( 'completed', '', true );
    }elseif ( $new_status == "completed" ) {
        
        ## Download Code
        
    }
}
```

The file is created in the server but how to download the file after the status changed to "completed" ?

I basically need the browser to download the file as it do with any other download.

Comment: The hook `woocommerce_order_status_changed` doesn't allow to download a file, It is just triggered on WooCommerce order status change **background process**. Also `$order` variable is undefined in your code *(it is missing from your hooked function arguments as 4th argument)*.

Comment: On which page should the file be downloaded? In the frontend or in the admin? Is it a custom page? You could show a link by checking 2 things: if the order has the completed status and if the file exists. This link may be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35268755/how-to-create-a-file-download-link-in-a-page-template and

Comment: Basically, the user will open the product page, fill in the details, and press a button which will create the order and change it to processing status (the file will be created), automatically it will become completed and the file should start to download at the user browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try `woocommerce_order_status_completed` action hook. this hook will fire once the order is completed. check the below code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'executeFile', 10 );
function executeFile( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    file_put_contents(wp_upload_dir()['basedir'].'/filetodownload.txt', 'some text');
}
```